# Mail-based submission : Does not show in the body of the email

Tags: html

I have created a simple form (mail-based submission). However, when I submit and when I am directed to the mail app, I don't see the text I have input to the "First Name" and "Surname" box. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<form action="mailto:someone@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
   First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /> <br/>
   Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /> <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
   </form>
```

Comment: I can't find a problem you described here https://jsfiddle.net/mdx3k9qv/

Comment: I have rectified the problem. Thanks!